# Garbage value in pop_back, Doubly Linked List in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

In the following code, I implemented the doubly linked list. I am getting the output as `56 2 3 4 0` instead of `56 2 3 4`. However, if I remove `lt.erase(5); lt.push_back(46);` then I get the correct output. I first thought that `erase()` have some bugs but by individually testing every function they seem fine to me. However, in this combination, I am getting an extra `0`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class LinkedList {
private:
    T data;
    LinkedList *prev, *next, *head, *tail;
public:
    LinkedList() : next(nullptr), head(nullptr), tail(nullptr), prev(nullptr){}
    LinkedList* get_node(T);
    void push_back(T);
    void insert(int, T);
    void pop_bak();
    void erase(int);
    void print();
};

template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>* LinkedList<T>:: get_node(T element) {
    auto* new_node = new LinkedList;
    new_node -> data = element;
    new_node -> prev = nullptr;
    new_node ->next = nullptr;
    return new_node;
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>:: push_back(T element) {
    static LinkedList *temp;
    if(head == nullptr) {
        head = get_node(element);
        tail = head;
        temp = head;
    } else {
        LinkedList *node = get_node(element);
        tail->next = node;
        tail = node;
        tail->prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>:: insert(int position, T element) {
    LinkedList *node = get_node(element);
    if(position == 1){
        head->prev = node;
        node->next = head;
        head = node;
    } else {
        LinkedList *start = head;
        int it = 1;
        while (it < position - 1) {
            start = start->next;
            ++it;
        }
        node->next = start->next;
        node->prev = start;
        start->next = node;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>:: pop_bak() {
    LinkedList *temp;
    temp = tail;
    tail = tail->prev;
    tail->next = nullptr;
    delete temp;
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>:: erase(int position) {
    LinkedList *temp;
    if(position == 1){
        temp = head;
        head = head ->next;
        delete temp;
    } else {
        LinkedList *start = head;
        int it = 1;
        while (it < position - 1) {
            start = start->next;
            ++it;
        }
        if(start->next == tail) {
            temp = tail;
            tail = tail ->prev;
            tail->next = nullptr;
            delete temp;
        } else {
            temp = start -> next;
            start ->next = start ->next->next;
            delete temp;
        }
    }
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>:: print() {
    LinkedList *start = head;
    while(start != tail->next) {
        cout << start->data << " ";
        start = start->next;
    }
}

int main() {
    LinkedList<int> lt;
    lt.push_back(2);
    lt.push_back(3);
    lt.push_back(4);
    lt.push_back(5);
    lt.insert(1, 56);
    lt.erase(5); // Remove this
    lt.push_back(46); // And this and it works perfectly. Where is the bug?
    lt.pop_bak();
    lt.print();
}
```

Comment: Just as a note here: Think about splitting your class in two (List & ListNode). Right now any instance has two useless members (either `prev` and `next` or `head` and `tail` are always `nullptr`). It's also counter intuitvie that `get_node` would return a `LinkedList`.

Comment: @churill may you please be little more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

`static LinkedList *temp;` in `push_back` seems like a lazy hack. It's not needed and your code get's even shorter without this:

```
template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::push_back(T element) {
    if (head == nullptr) {
        head = get_node(element);
        tail = head;
    }
    else {
        LinkedList* node = get_node(element);
        tail->next = node;
        node->prev = tail;
        tail = node;
    }
}
```

But that's just the error I found for this specific problem. Zan Lynx is probably right, there may be more bugs.

### Explanation

You get undefined behaviour because you access deleted memory. The bug or design failure is the `static LinkedList *temp;` in `push_back`. Note that this `temp` will always point to the last pushed element. But at some point you delete the last element! So let's take it step by step:

After `lt.push_back(5);` your list looks like this:

```
                         temp (from push_back)
                         |
56 <-> 2 <-> 3 <-> 4 <-> 5 -> nullptr
|                        |
head                     tail
```

Now erase `delete`s the node with value 5. But `temp` still points to the memory that was freed<sup>1</sup>, so you get:

```
                        temp (from push_back)
                        |
56 <-> 2 <-> 3 <-> 4    5 [freed]
|                  |
head               tail
```

After the next line `lt.push_back(46);` things go crazy. You have the following code (simplyfied):

```
void LinkedList<T>::push_back(T element) {
    static LinkedList* temp;
    if (head == nullptr) {...}
    else {
        LinkedList* node = get_node(element);
        tail->next = node;                   
        tail = node;                         
        tail->prev = temp; // prev->temp is now pointing to freed memory
        temp = temp->next; // dereferencing an invalid pointer -> undefined behaviour
    }
}
```

This results in:

```
                                          temp (from push_back)
         5 [deleted] <-                   |
56 <-> 2 <-> 3 <-> 4 -> 46  -> nullptr    ????  
|                       |
head                    tail
```

Then everything goes to hell in handbasket with `lt.pop_bak();`:

```
void LinkedList<T>::pop_bak() {
    LinkedList* temp;
    temp = tail;
    tail = tail->prev;    // tail->prev is an invalid pointer, now tail is too
    tail->next = nullptr; // dereferencing invalid pointer (again)
    delete temp;
}
```

```
                        temp (from pop_bak)                 
                        |                                   
56 <-> 2 <-> 3 <-> 4 -> 46 [deleted] -> nullptr     5 [deleted] -> nullptr
|                                                   |
head                                                tail
```

As you see your list got completely cut up and you got two pointers that point to freed memory (e.g. memory you don't own that contains garbage data). Just because you saved a pointer in `static LinkedList *temp;` in `push_back`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Though in C++ you use `delete` and not the C-function `free`, I refer to "freed memory" because it's clearer in my opinion. The memory is still there, it just doesn't belong to your program any more

Answer (score 1):

Write a function to test the validity of your list. After every operation call this function. If the list is not valid, call `abort()` to break into your debugger. The last operation is the buggy one.

For one thing, just looking at your code I am pretty sure you aren't keeping your double links correctly. I see you adjusting next links but never the prev links.